# batch script having input redirection called from cmd adds numeric arguments automatically

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a cmd batch script named runcmd.bat as follows

```
plink.exe -ssh 1.11.1.1 -l kaka -pw babay < commands.txt >output.txt
```

when this batch script is called from CMD, it generates the following error:

```
 C:\Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY>runCmd.bat

C:\Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY>c:

C:\Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY>cd \

C:\>cd "Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY"

C:\Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY>plink.exe -ssh 1.11.1.1 -l kaka -pw babay  0<commands.txt 1>>output.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY>
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If you can see, it automatically adds 0 and 1 before < and > input and output redirections operators.

I'm using Windows 8.1 x64. I have also tried this same in windows 2012 R2 Server but all ended up showing the same.

I expect that the script executes without adding any number before input and output redirector.

Comment: Those numbers are absolutely the correct syntax for input and output redirection. There is no error other than you've been used to using lazy syntax ,`>`, `>>` and `<`. Your issue is that either `C:\Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY\commands.txt` does not exist or `plink.exe` is not in `C:\Users\ASAD\Desktop\PuTTY` or found under `%PATH%`.

Comment: But the batchscript doesnot work. if these numbers are added. Additionally, if i run this batch file directly. the results returns as expected and NO number is added

Comment: Are you sure you have a commands.txt file in the PuTTY directory? That would be very unusual.

Comment: I have added that file my self.

Comment: Can you double-check by going into the PuTTY directory and typing `DIR commands.txt`?

Comment: You are wrong, the numbers are not your issue, the system cannot find the file you specified, it tells you that clearly in its message.

Comment: Implied, but left unsaid so far - it is impossible to run a batch script command with redirection while ECHO is ON without those numbers being introduced. 0 stands for stdin, and 1 stands for stdout. When you run a command from the command line without a batch script, the command is never ECHOed, so you don't see the numbers. Some file does not exist where you think it does - most likely "commands.txt". We have all been there - banging our heads against the wall until we realize something we "know" to be true simply isn't true. Take a breath and figure out what file is missing.

Comment: Compo and dbenham Thank you so much I figured it out and corrected the command.txt path and issue resolved. Thanks for your swift response. Feeling blessed